# Select text except hyperlinks?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, hyperlink

Sometimes, I would like to change the color of the text in a Word document without affecting the color of hyperlinks. If I simply press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and change font color, then the color of hyperlinks is changed too and it becomes no longer possible to discern them from regular text.

This happens a lot when I paste from an external page and I would like the regular font to appear black, but if I use press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the pasted text, then the hyperlinks turn black as well.

Is there a way to highlight all regular text in a document without manually going through and changing the color of intervals of regular text between hyperlinks?

*Note: **I don't want to change the style or theme color for regular font**; I want to simply change font color excepting hyperlinks. I foresee this (if possible) being done by somehow being able to select text, omitting hyperlinks, or change color, omitting hyperlinks.*

Comment: You really should use Word's "Styles" - then changing the color of all regular text can be done with just two or three clicks.

Comment: Theme and Styles are different features which serve different purposes. Your note made no mention of Styles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After setting the font settings, run this macro to reset the font style for all hyperlinks.

```
Sub RestoreHyperlinkStyle()
    Dim hl As Hyperlink
    For Each hl In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        hl.Range.Style = wdStyleHyperlink
    Next
End Sub
```